# how to show table column only in mobile view in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

In our project we are showing a table with many columns. In mobile view we want to additional column for bootstrap 4 table. we have option to hide row for all views but its not optimal. Is there class which can be used to show the column only for mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is class available `d-sm-block`, you can set this class to table & for desktop d-md-none is available for hide. you can refer this link for more info 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: for mobile it should be d-xs not sm i think.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div class="d-md-none">hide on md and wider screens</div>
```